# Playing sound to bluetooth speaker using .Net Maui

Tags: maui

I'm working on an application that I intend on having it run on both Android and IoS.  I'm currently working on the IoS application which I am running / debugging on an iPad. It works great running with the default speakers / microphone on the iPad.

I create a new project to test just the play audio part.  This is the code I am using:

```
var audioPlayer = AudioManager.Current.CreatePlayer(await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("test.mp3"));

audioPlayer.Play();
```

When I run this application on the iPad, it plays the sound on the iPad as expected.  I then connect to a bluetooth speaker on the iPad and run the application and it still plays on the iPad. I need this application to automatically send audio to the bluetooth device and receive audio from the bluetooth mic when the bluetooth device is connected on the iPad or Android host.  What am I missing and how does the audio get routed when a bluetooth device is connected?

Then, on the IPad, I turn the bluetooth speaker on the iPad and run the application again, but the sound still plays on the iPad.

I opened other applications on the iPad and played sounds / music to the bluetooth speaker just fine.

I did an extensive search out there, and it looks like all the bluetooth libraries are for managing connections, not playing something to the devices.  I was assuming the OS would handle where to play the sound when the bluetooth was trained / turned onto a device.

I haven't moved over the mic recording yet into the test application to see if that works, that will be next on my list when I get the audio playing.

Comment: https://github.com/jfversluis/Plugin.Maui.Audio/issues/53

Comment: OMG. This worked! That truly was a needle in the haystack! Thank you, @Jason!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off of what @Jason posted, this is the code that got it working.  I wasn't sure it was looking at the link but this needs to be injected at the AppDelegate for iOS. (AppDelegate.cs)

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
{
    SetAudioSession();

    return base.FinishedLaunching(application, launchOptions);
}

public bool SetAudioSession()
{
    var audioSession = AVAudioSession.SharedInstance();
    var err = audioSession.SetCategory(AVAudioSessionCategory.PlayAndRecord, AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.AllowBluetooth |
                                       AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.AllowBluetooth | AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.AllowAirPlay |
                                       AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.DefaultToSpeaker);
    if (err != null)
        return false;

    err = audioSession.SetActive(true);

    if (err != null)
        return false;

    return true;

}+
```